# Non-null field is null with Glide

Tags: android, kotlin, nullable, android-glide

I use glide in my Kotlin project.
Currently, Java and Kotlin are mixed.
And I saw crash report from below code. (Not always but some user have this issue)

```
Glide.with(view.context)
                .load(HoianImage(images[position].file()))
                .asBitmap()
                .dontAnimate()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                .listener(object : RequestListener<HoianImage, Bitmap> {
                    override fun onException(e: Exception, model: HoianImage, target: Target<Bitmap>, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                        hideProgressBar(progressBar)
                        return false
                    }

                    override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, model: HoianImage, target: Target<Bitmap>, isFromMemoryCache: Boolean, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                        hideProgressBar(progressBar)
                        return false
                    }
                }).into(imageView)
```

The hideProgressBar() method signature is like below.

```
private fun hideProgressBar(progressBar: ProgressBar?) {
        progressBar?.visibility = View.GONE
    }
```

And the following is my crash report.

```
Exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method hsa.a, parameter e
com.towneers.www.ui.adapter.ImageViewAdapter$instantiateItem$1.onException$6f56094 (ImageViewAdapter.java:88)
com.towneers.www.ui.adapter.ImageViewAdapter$instantiateItem$1.onResourceReady$25390db0 (ImageViewAdapter.java:88)
com.bumptech.glide.request.GenericRequest.onException (GenericRequest.java:547)
com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.EngineJob.handleExceptionOnMainThread (EngineJob.java:183)
com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.EngineJob.access$200 (EngineJob.java:22)
com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.EngineJob$MainThreadCallback.handleMessage (EngineJob.java:204)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:98)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6776)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1496)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1386)'
```

I also attached Proguard mapping file.

```
com.towneers.www.ui.adapter.ImageViewAdapter$instantiateItem$1 -> hsa:
    com.towneers.www.ui.adapter.ImageViewAdapter this$0 -> a
    android.widget.ProgressBar $progressBar -> b
    88:88:boolean onException$6f56094(java.lang.Exception,java.lang.Object,com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target) -> a
    1090:1091:boolean onException$4d4a0d67(java.lang.Exception,com.towneers.www.core.glide.HoianImage,com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target):90:91 -> a
    1090:1091:boolean onException$6f56094(java.lang.Exception,java.lang.Object,com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target):88 -> a
    88:88:boolean onResourceReady$25390db0(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object,com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target) -> a
    1095:1096:boolean onResourceReady$19e372f5(android.graphics.Bitmap,com.towneers.www.core.glide.HoianImage,com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target):95:96 -> a
    1095:1096:boolean onResourceReady$25390db0(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object,com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target):88 -> a
    88:88:void <init>(com.towneers.www.ui.adapter.ImageViewAdapter,android.widget.ProgressBar) -> <init>
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Glide docs](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/330/com/bumptech/glide/request/RequestListener.html) the parameter `e` (the `Exception`) might be a `null`. In your Kotlin implementation however the parameter is marked as non-optional. And this causes a (runtime) crash when the method gets called with a `null`.

Fix in this case would be to change the signature of the `onException` function to:

```
override fun onException(e: Exception?, model: HoianImage, target: Target<Bitmap>, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean
```

Note the questionmark added.

Kotlin makes all paramters non-optional when implementing interfaces/methods. It only adds the `?` when the method in the Java interface has a `@Nullable` annotation on it. It happens quite a lot when implementing Java/Android interfaces in Android.

Comment: Thanks! I think you are right. I will do modify Exception param to optional and see my issue fixed. Because of this issue, I also trying to change my all java code to Kotlin.